# htaccess redirect for friendly URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I currently have a .htaccess file that works well. So far I have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
#first part
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.net/$1 [R=301,L]

#second part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2/$3.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

#third part
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

The very first line is needed for me because I use GoDaddy hosting.
The first part is redirecting www.mydomain.net to mydomain.net.
Second part is redirecting mydomain.net/abcd to mydomain.net/abcd.php.
Third part is getting rid of .php at the end of URL.

Now I need to add codes that will redirect mydomain.net/products/?category=electronics to mydomain.net/products/electronics, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried adding "RewriteRule /products/(.*)$ /products/?category=$1" and many other codes that I found on Stack Overflow, but none of them seems to work for me.

Thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.net/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(products)/\?category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(products)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/?category=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2/$3.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: @anubhava are you here? may I ask you something?

Comment: maybe in chat? I asked a question but it was closed as it is a dublicate but I could not find the exact dublicate and that is why I wanted to contact you.. Maybe in chat for 1 min?

Comment: Oh I see, no better tonight if I catch you :) Mobile is for talks, not for works :) thanks mate !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67720/discussion-between-europeuser-and-anubhava).

Comment: I am sending you messages from chat but not sure if you received them?

Comment: I think I found the answer